# DataTables - How to get cell from specific row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Every row has an ID, #row-(id from ajax).
Now I want to select an row by id, I got this to work.

```
var row = verzondenTable.row('#row-' + k);
```

k = the key from ajax.

Every td has a class per column so the first column has the class `.td-subject` and the second one has `.td-open`.

I want to select the `.td-open` cell from the specific selected row and set the data for it.

Code:

```
$().ready(function() {
    var verzondenTable = $('#tblVerzondenItems').DataTable({
        "order": [[0,'desc']],
        "columnDefs":[
            { "type": "date-nl", "targets": [ 'th-datum' ] },
            {
                sortable: false,
                targets: [6,7]
            }
            ],
        "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
            $.ajax({
                url : '/mail/feed/mailgun.json',
                type : 'GET',
                dataType:'json',
                success : function(data) {
                    $.each(data, function(k,v) {

                        var row = verzondenTable.row('#row-' + k);
                        verzondenTable.row('#row-' + k).cell('.td-open').data((v['open_rate'] * 100).toFixed(2) + '%');

                    });
                    $('#alert-mailgun').alert('close');
                },
                error : function(request,error)
                {
                    alert("Request: "+JSON.stringify(request));
                }
            });
        }
    });
    // loop over each element and create a tooltip using the data-attribute
    $('.count').each(function() {
        Tipped.create(this, {
            ajax: {
                data: $(this).data('querystring'),
                type: "POST"
            },
            maxWidth: 300,
            skin: 'dark'
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go through the API you can do something like

```
var row = verzondenTable.row('#row-' + k);
row.nodes().to$().find('.td-open').text((v['open_rate'] * 100).toFixed(2) + '%');
row.draw().invalidate();
```

`nodes()` -> get all nodes
`to$()` -> convert to jQuery instance
`invalidate` -> update DT internals

Answer (score 0):

How about using CSS selectors:

```
$('[id^="row-"] td.td-open').text(your_data);//your_data is the value you want to set.
```

Comment: I can't use this because I also have pagination, so it won't find all rows. And I have print functions that uses the datatables cell data

Comment: @MikeLammers but you must be having unique ID per row, right?

Answer (score 0):

try this `function row().child( data [, className ] )` from reference https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().child()